# How to customize Statistics table view on Jmeter report dashboard

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I'm using jmeter 3.2 version and i'm running jmx file using jmeter-maven-pulgin(v2.4.0) run and generate html report. But the report needs to be customized as per the below requirement
1) Statistics table should display the result according to Execution timings(Exact structure like View Result tree )
2) How customize the Statistics table so that samplers result are not clubbed and displayed.
3) While running from pom.xml, property files under bin folder will be re-generated because of which my configuration be deleted. How to avoid re-generation of property files